# Laravel Eager loading doesn't work unless I select primary key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables: students and clubs, which have a many to many relationship.

I want to return all the students along with their clubs as part of an ajax call, but I want to exclude the student primary key, because this gives unintended information about the number of students in the system.

```
$students = Student::all()
     ->with('clubs')
     ->select('students.name', 'students.grade', 'students.birthday')
     ->get();
```

This returns an empty array for clubs.
If I change the third line to include id, it works flawlessly.

```
$students = Student::all()
     ->with('clubs')
     ->select('students.id', 'students.name', 'students.grade', 'students.birthday')
     ->get();
```

What is the best way to go about excluding the primary key? Should I just remove it by looping through the collection after the query?

Comment: Do you have any pivot table like `club_student`?

Comment: @Viney Yes, I do.

Comment: Try this `Student::with('clubs')
     ->select('students.name', 'students.grade', 'students.birthday')
     ->get();`

Comment: Not sure what happened but that gives me an internal server error 500.

Comment: @Viney Turns out I left out the get statement. The request completes now, but the clubs array is still empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `forget` from collection

`https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forget`

Comment: I had no idea this existed! Thank you very much.